# Drupal removes tags from body of page

Tags: html, drupal, tags, strip

How do I stop Drupal from removing tags from the body of a page??

If I create a page that is organized such as

```
    <p>blah blah</p>
    <p>blah blah 2</p>
```

When I go back and edit - it removes the p and when I publish even without editing it turns into this

blah blahblah blah2

It's really annoying especially when editing pages with a lot of content - because I have to redo everything..!!

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like drupal is sanitizing the content, removing html tags

Answer (score 1):

What input filter are you using? It sounds like the wrong one is being used.

Sounds like you might be using either plain text or filtered HTML.

From Drupal, details for Filtered HTML:

> • Web page addresses and e-mail addresses turn into links automatically.
>   • Allowed HTML tags: `<a> <em> <strong> <cite> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd>`
>   • Lines and paragraphs break automatically.

To see and configure your input filters go to `admin/settings/filters` or `/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html`

Comment: I agree. You should be using Full Html